# Clean up [change] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Is there any specific meaning to the [change](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/change) tag?  There is no tag wiki, and I don't see that the 33 questions that currently carry that tag have much of anything in common.  There are questions about swapping hardware, changing file permissions, watching for file modifications, resetting passwords, … basically a hodgepodge.

On the other hand, [change-management](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/change-management) seems to be a legitimate topic that deserves to have a tag.

What should be done about the [change](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/change) tag?  Burninate?  Surgical clean-up?

Comment: It looks like you have broad agreement to burninate - it's your idea so it's up to you to organise it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My vote goes to burninate - it's adding nothing.

Comment: Without further clarification, it's always going to end up as a dumping ground for questions from people thinking "well I'm changing my socks while doing this so...", or whatever, so yeah burniate for sure.

Comment: @RobM It looks like people try to use it as [tag:change] [tag:password] or similar not realising that the tags get ordered by popularity ...

Comment: yah. either way, holding its feet to the fire should fix things